# R RStoolbox not picking up a SpatialPolygonDataFrame as a Polygon

Tags: r, image-classification

I am trying to perform a `supervised classification` via `RStoolbox`. I am using a `SpatialPolygonDataFrame` as the training data. Now, even though `rgdal` picks up the polygon, `RStoolbox` returns an error.

Datatype:

[image]

```
 Error: traingData must POINTs or a POLYGONs
```

How can I fix this?

Code:

```
library(sf)
library(rgdal)
library(RStoolbox)

sf = st_read("path/polygon")

sp = st_as_sf(sf)

# Supervised classification 

SC = superClass(img = rst, model = "rf", trainData = sp,
                         responseCol = "Feature")
```

Sample Data:

```
structure(list(acres = c(0.641654059155, 0.0576189697318), County = c("Palm Beach", 
"Palm Beach"), AerialsYea = c("2013", "2013"), Feature = c("Dune", 
"Dune"), MeanElevFt = c(10.7327470779, 10.4281425476), BeachWidth = c(126.341505995, 
90.0029897781), Shape_Leng = c(687.02934164, 243.391842959), 
    Shape_Area = c(27950.3390151, 2509.872282), geometry = structure(list(
        structure(list(list(structure(c(959372.800088584, 959379.050076086, 
        959389.466721918, 959398.321034919, 959404.050026085, 
        959411.341678169, 959413.946003668, 959417.591665667, 
        959419.674994834, 959428.008311503, 959436.8626245, 959442.591615669, 
        959449.3625995, 959455.612587001, 959461.862574503, 959466.549901083, 
        959474.362549502, 959483.737530749, 959491.029182833, 
        959499.362499502, 959505.612486999, 959511.862474501, 
        959517.070797417, 959522.800116669, 959528.008439586, 
        959529.570772417, 959529.050104167, 959532.69576617, 
        959537.383420836, 959534.779095333, 959533.160004083, 
        959529.570772417, 959524.883445833, 959525.404114086, 
        959521.237455752, 959519.154126585, 959519.154126585, 
        959519.675122917, 959519.675122917, 959520.195791166, 
        959517.591793749, 959517.070797417, 959513.425135419, 
        959510.300141666, 959510.820809919, 959507.175147917, 
        959502.487493251, 959494.675172918, 959487.383520834, 
        959477.487543251, 959472.279220335, 959465.508236501, 
        959459.779245336, 959450.924932335, 959438.424957335, 
        959428.529307835, 959422.279320333, 959414.98766825, 
        959406.654351585, 959397.800038584, 959385.820731834, 
        959372.800088584, 959363.945775583, 959354.570794333, 
        959354.050126083, 959354.570794333, 959357.175119836, 
        959359.258448999, 959361.862446416, 959363.945775583, 
        959364.987440169, 959367.070769336, 959369.1540985, 959370.195763085, 
        959370.716759417, 959372.800088584, 725529.748456582, 
        725530.790121168, 725525.060801916, 725522.977472752, 
        725524.019137338, 725520.894143589, 725528.706792004, 
        725535.998444088, 725538.081773251, 725537.560776919, 
        725534.43578317, 725529.748456582, 725530.269124836, 
        725529.22746025, 725531.310789421, 725534.956779502, 
        725539.644106083, 725543.290096171, 725544.852429003, 
        725543.810764417, 725545.894093588, 725542.769099839, 
        725538.081773251, 725528.185795672, 725520.894143589, 
        725513.081823252, 725509.956829503, 725506.310839422, 
        725503.185845666, 725495.894193582, 725488.60713467, 
        725483.394218586, 725477.665227421, 725470.894243583, 
        725465.164924338, 725453.185945667, 725444.331632666, 
        725434.435983166, 725430.269324839, 725419.852678999, 
        725414.644356087, 725405.269374833, 725400.06105192, 
        725388.602741502, 725381.831757672, 725368.290118083, 
        725360.998466, 725354.22748217, 725350.581820168, 725350.581820168, 
        725348.498491004, 725349.01915925, 725349.540155582, 
        725354.748478502, 725359.956801422, 725363.602463417, 
        725362.560798839, 725357.873472251, 725356.310811333, 
        725356.310811333, 725356.831807666, 725356.831807666, 
        725359.435805082, 725361.519134253, 725371.415111832, 
        725384.956751421, 725396.936058171, 725412.040030584, 
        725431.310989417, 725443.289968088, 725455.789943084, 
        725471.935908169, 725489.644206084, 725501.102516502, 
        725516.727485254, 725529.748456582, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05
        ), .Dim = c(76L, 3L)))), class = c("XYZ", "MULTIPOLYGON", 
        "sfg")), structure(list(list(structure(c(959545.195741169, 
        959559.258377083, 959563.946031749, 959567.591693752, 
        959562.904367168, 959559.258377083, 959555.091718752, 
        959553.529385917, 959555.394211583, 959548.957872752, 
        959533.737430751, 959524.883445833, 959525.404114086, 
        959529.050104167, 959531.133433335, 959532.69576617, 
        959534.779095333, 959530.612437002, 959530.091768753, 
        959535.820759919, 959541.550079167, 959545.195741169, 
        725501.102516502, 725488.081873253, 725478.706892006, 
        725464.644256085, 725454.227610253, 725446.414961837, 
        725438.602641501, 725426.623334751, 725413.128283001, 
        725403.181452505, 725399.019387335, 725399.540055588, 
        725411.519362338, 725419.852678999, 725430.269324839, 
        725439.123309754, 725451.62328475, 725454.227610253, 
        725463.6025915, 725477.144231088, 725490.68587067, 725501.102516502, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, -2.34999999975116e-05, 
        -2.34999999975116e-05), .Dim = c(22L, 3L)))), class = c("XYZ", 
        "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON", 
    "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 959354.050126083, 
    ymin = 725348.498491004, xmax = 959567.591693752, ymax = 725545.894093588
    ), class = "bbox"), z_range = structure(c(zmin = -2.34999999975116e-05, 
    zmax = -2.34999999975116e-05), class = "z_range"), crs = structure(list(
        input = "NAD83 / Florida East (ftUS)", wkt = "PROJCRS[\"NAD83 / Florida East (ftUS)\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"NAD83\",\n        DATUM[\"North American Datum 1983\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",6269]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]]],\n    CONVERSION[\"unnamed\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",24.3333333333333,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",-81,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.999941176470588,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",656166.666666667,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9003]]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9003]]]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(acres = NA_integer_, 
County = NA_integer_, AerialsYea = NA_integer_, Feature = NA_integer_, 
MeanElevFt = NA_integer_, BeachWidth = NA_integer_, Shape_Leng = NA_integer_, 
Shape_Area = NA_integer_), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not coercing to an sp class. The `st_read` function is resulting in a sf class MULTIPOLYGON object. Since this is likely representing AOI's, I would recommend first exploding the geometry to single part using `st_cast(x, "POLYGON")` then coercing to sp using `as(x, "Spatial")`. The reason being is that if you extract spectral information for each AOI polygon a multi-part geometry will return the statistic for the group of polygons associated with the multi-part feature and not each individual polygon.

In looking at the object you provided there is a z value associated with the polygon feature class. To coerce to sp you must first drop the z values. This is exactly why we need reproducible examples so, thank you!

Here is a work flow that should get you an appropriate sp object (ignore the warning associated with repeating sub-geometries).

```
library(sp)
library(sf)

tdat <- sf::st_zm(sf::st_read("path/polygon"), drop=TRUE)
tdat.sp <- as(sf::st_cast(tdat, "POLYGON"), "Spatial")
```

Comment: so I used `Training_Data = st_cast(Training_Data, "POLYGON") %>% 
                as(Training_Data, "Spatial") ` but it returns an error  `Error in .findMethodInTable(c(from, to), methods) : 
  variable names are limited to 10000 bytes`

Comment: @Arthur_Morgan Please see my edits regarding z values. Also, I do not believe your pipe syntax is correct and honestly, it is unnecessary, try: `as(st_cast(Training_Data, "POLYGON"), "Spatial")`